# Pact with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, pact

I am trying to follow the Baeldung Pact Tutorial with SpringBoot

https://www.baeldung.com/pact-junit-consumer-driven-contracts

I have one GET and one POST Method in my service as follows:

```
public class BaeldungTest {
    @Rule
    public PactProviderRuleMk2 mockProvider
    = new PactProviderRuleMk2("test_provider", "localhost", 8080, this);

    @Pact(consumer = "test_consumer")
    public RequestResponsePact createPactGet(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
     
        return builder
          .given("test GET")
            .uponReceiving("GET REQUEST")
            .path("/pact")
            .method("GET")
          .willRespondWith()
            .status(200)
            .headers(headers)
            .body("{\"condition\": true, \"name\": \"tom\"}")
           .given("test POST")
           .uponReceiving("POST REQUEST")
             .method("POST")
             .headers(headers)
             .body("{\"name\": \"Michael\"}")
              .path("/create")
            .willRespondWith()
              .status(201)
              .headers(headers)
              .body("")
            .toPact();
           
    }
 

@Test
@PactVerification()
public void GETRequestTest_whenSendRequest_shouldReturn200WithProperHeaderAndBody() {
     
        // when
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate()
          .getForEntity(mockProvider.getUrl() + "/pact", String.class);      
        // then
        assertEquals(200,response.getStatusCode().value());
        assertTrue(response.getHeaders().get("Content-Type").contains("application/json"));
      
    }

    @Test
    @PactVerification()
    public void POSTRequestTest_whenSendRequest_shouldReturn201WithProperHeaderAndBody() {
     
        // when
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        String jsonBody = "{\"name\": \"Michael\"}";

       // when
       ResponseEntity<String> postResponse = new RestTemplate()
      .exchange(
        mockProvider.getUrl() + "/create",
        HttpMethod.POST,
        new HttpEntity<String>(jsonBody, httpHeaders), 
        String.class
      );

    //then
    assertEquals(201, postResponse.getStatusCode().value());          
    }
 

 }
```

Now, if I run the Get Service Test, I get the error that the Post Request was not received

```
  au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactMismatchesException: The following requests were not received:
    method: POST
    path: /create
    query: [:]
    headers: [Content-Type:application/json]
    ...
```

For the POST Test, I get the error that the GET Request was not received:
au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactMismatchesException: The following requests were not received:
method: POST
path: /create
query: [:]
headers: [Content-Type:application/json]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a single integration inside the actual contract, extract each call to a separate contract. Then you have to explicitly declare the pact that will be used as mock like this:

```java
@PactVerification(value = "test_provider", fragment = "createPactGet")
```

where `fragment` is the `@Pact` method name